JPA fails to update with empty list
In my Java/SpringBoot JPA app, I have the following query to cancel lapsed Subscriptions:
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update Subscription s set s.status='canceled' where s.ident not in (:currentSubscriptions)")
void cancelMissing(@Param("currentSubscriptions") List<String> currentSubscriptions);

When this query is executed with an empty list, I would expect all subscriptions to have their status updated to 'canceled', however none of the subscriptions in my DB have been updated.
The query updates everything if I remove the where clause.
How should I diagnose where the issue lies?

Start by looking at the underlying SQL generated by Spring for this. If it converts an empty list to null, consider that not in ( null ) and in ( null ) both typically return empty result sets in the SQL dialects I am familiar with. See Empty IN clause parameter list in MySQL.
